# What happened to "Flags" moderation tool?

Tags: support, 10k-tools

There used to be a FLAGS tab in https://askubuntu.com/tools. What happened?

[image]

The same in meta:

[image]

Comment: Per Oli's answer below it would be wonderfully helpful if you kept a tight eye on the low quality post queue, now that the flag queue is gone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[It was rolled up into the standard review process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226092/lets-get-rid-of-the-10k-flag-queue). Here's part of [Shog9's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228861/144180):

> /tools/flagged is no more. Disputed flags are still a thing, but disputes are situations observed by the system, not explicit actions. The guidance for new 10K users has been revised: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools